# Assigning values from a text file into a variable that can be used for next step in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python scripts. I wanted to create a script that can opened a text file, c_name.txt where the content of the text file would be list of cell names. After i opened, i need to assign all the cell names as a variable. This is because i need the cell name to open up the next directory which requires the cell name. What i did for now is to open the text file and print the cell names. I do not know on how to read the cell name and assign to a variable. Do i need to assign all the cell names into an array?

I also need to classify if cell name starts with ce_, then the report files will be in ce_ directory whereas if the cell name starts with cell, then the report files will be in cell directory.

Here is my c_name.txt:

```
ce_clk
celladd
ce_sum
cellsub
```

Here is the updated code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import os.path

myPWD = os.getcwd()

# Implement functions get_test_directory and get_library_directory
# to retrieve correct directory paths
def get_test_directory( str ):
    return str

def get_library_directory (str ):
    os.chdir('..')
    str = os.getcwd()
    return str

test_directory = get_test_directory(myPWD)
library_directory = get_library_directory(myPWD)

cell_names_file = os.path.join(test_directory, "c_name.txt")

with open(cell_names_file, "r+") as f1:
    cell_names = f1.readlines()

for cell_name in cell_names:
    cell_directory = "ce_" if cell_name.startswith("ce_") else "cell"
    floc2 = os.path.join(library_directory, cell_directory, "{0}.rpt".format(cell_name))
    with open(floc2, "r+") as f2:
        for line in f2:
                 print line
```

NEW EDITED:
I am having another problem with line startswith  on making it more generic instead of using hardcoded like below:

```
for cell_name in cell_names:
        cell_directory = "ce_" if cell_name.startswith("ce_") else "cell"
        floc2 = os.path.join(library_directory, cell_directory,{0}.rpt".format(cell_name))
```

For now I am using "ce_" and "cell", is it possible to like ask the script to read the cell_name first 3 char, which is "ce_" and "cel" instead of defining it myself. I tried using this line but it seems not working as it shows error:

```
cell_directory = cell_name.startswith(cell_name,0,5)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current example, it would be sufficient to store the values into a list. Later, when you need these values, iterate over the list and get each cell name one by one.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import os.path

myPWD = os.getcwd()

# Implement functions get_test_directory and get_library_directory
# to retrieve correct directory paths
test_directory = get_test_directory(myPWD)
library_directory = get_library_directory(myPWD)

cell_names_file = os.path.join(test_directory, "c_name.txt")

with open(cell_names_file, "r+") as f1:
    cell_names = [line.strip() for line in f1]

for cell_name in cell_names:
    cell_directory = "ce_" if cell_name.startswith("ce_") else "cell"
    floc2 = os.path.join(library_directory, cell_directory, "{0}.rpt".format(cell_name))
```

EDIT: The code was updated to account for the new information from the question. There is no precise information about the directory structure, so I'm using dummy placeholders.

Comment: I am having problem when i want to open cellname.rpt as they could not find the directory. This is because directory test and library are in same level. However, from my script, the script thought that library is one level down after test. Error: workspace/test/../library/ce_clk.rpt. The actual location is workspace/library/ce_clk.rpt.

Comment: You are defining the path in your code: `workspace = "%s/.." %(myPWD)`. Remove the reference to the parent folder ('..') and it should work if the structure is what you say it is.

Comment: I tried removing ('..') and it became workspace = "%s" %(myPWD), but then i got error for the first floc:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mmaz.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(floc, "r+") as f1:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/workspace/test/test/c_name.txt'

Comment: And somehow, i already modified my question above where i need to identify the cell starts with ce_ or cell

Comment: @mmaz The answer has been updated. It is not clear what your directory structure is, so there are two functions you need to implement.

Comment: My current directory which i run the script is /disks/user/mmaz/mmaz20/test/ . Directories contain under /mmaz20 is /test and /library which means test and library are at same level.

Comment: @mmaz Update the code in question with the one you are now using and paste the error message in the question. Formatting is not preserved inside comments and it's difficult to see what is happening.

Comment: I already updated the script in question above and stated the error

Comment: When Python reads the file contents, newline character (`\n`) is also read. It must be stripped manually. The code has been updated.

Comment: it works really well !! thank you for all the helps !!